Правильно ли здесь проставлены запятые?
Мы идем домой, как цари
Мы идем домой, хотя можно было и здесь остаться
Мы идем домой, когда придет время
Мы идем домой, потому что на улице холодно
Мы идем домой, если на улице будет темно

Кроме первого, все предложения сложноподчинённые, так что запятая нужна. В первом же сравнительный оборот и запятая тоже нужна, потому что "мы - не цари, но подобны царям".
